# How to count the number of documents in every collection in every databse?

Tags: python, json, mongodb, hex, pymongo

I have a number of mongoDB databses and collections on my computer:

```
{"key": [], "business-01": ["reviews", "system.indexes"], "test": [], "test_database": ["posts", "system.indexes"]}
```

And while I can count every collection by itself, how would I go about iterating over every one? I tried to use an aggregator:

```
results = sr2.aggregate([
{ group: {_id: null, count: {$sum: 1}}}
])
```

or using:

```
results = collection.aggregate([
    # Unwind the array
    { "$unwind": "$all" },

    # Group the results and count
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$somekey",
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

but all the configurations I tried just gave me random hex:

```
business-01 corresponds to ['reviews', 'system.indexes']
<pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor object at 0x7fa219f9b630>
<pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor object at 0x7fa219f9b630>
key corresponds to []
test corresponds to []
admin corresponds to []
```

I need a formatted output of each:

```
{id:business-01, col:reviews, feilds:21}
{id:business-01, col:system.indexes, feilds:0}
{id:test, col:na}
{id:test_database, col:posts, feilds:500}
{id:test_database, col:system.indexes, feilds:0}
```

I'm using pymongo on 64bit Ubuntu.

Comment: How about you just loop on the client side and run a pipeline like this (you don't need to `$group`): `collection.aggregate({$count: "count"})`? Ah, I see, you need counts per field, so grouping is required... Still, you could loop on the client side...

Comment: I got an invalid syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregrations are executed against a collection and not a database per say.

The count of documents for all collection in every database can be computed in python.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient()


result = []

for dbname in client.database_names():
    db = client[dbname]
    for collection in db.collection_names():
        count = db[collection].count()
        result.append({'id': dbname, 'col': collection, 'count': count})

print(result)
```

Answer (score 4):

pymongo says [count](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.count) is deprecated now. that's note:

> DeprecationWarning: count is deprecated. Use estimated_document_count
> or count_documents instead.

You can use `count_documents` like that:

```
count = collection.count_documents({})
```

### **Update:**

I've faced count issue today and I noticed count_documents method is not work well with massive collection. This is because [count_documents](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.count_documents) work like a query without any filter and scan whole collection. [estimated_document_count](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.estimated_document_count) is getting document count using collection metadata. Using `estimated_document_count` instead of `count_documents` solved my problem.